# How to enable Cloud Datastore API in GAE so that another GAE app can communicate with it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

We're trying to enable Google Cloud Datastore API for a Google App Engine application so that another App Engine app could directly get data from its datastore.

I have a problem configuring both apps for making this happen. In this page:

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate

Under the section "Google Cloud Datastore for accessing existing App Engine Datastore from other Platform" it is mentioned that we could "Register" our app, generate a certificate and download a private key. All these options are not present in the Google Cloud Console:

https://cloud.google.com/console#/project/{projectID}

I see there are no questions for Cloud Datastore yet. I hope someone answers this. We're a premier account customer and this could solve many of our problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs on that page were slightly out of date. Starting from your project page in the Cloud Console:

1. Select **APIs & auth** from the left hand navigation.
2. Scroll to the **Google Cloud Datastore API**.
3. Switch **Google Cloud Datastore API** from **OFF** to **ON**.
4. Click on **Credentials** in the left hand side menu.
5. Click on **CREATE NEW CLIENT ID**.
6. Select **Service account** and click **Create Client ID**. Your browser will download the private key.
7. Your **Service Account** is the **Email address** displayed under the **Service Account** section.
8. Your **Private Key** is the file you just downloaded.
9. Your **Dataset ID** is your App Engine **Application ID**.

You can also find the (updated) instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_accessing_existing_app_engine_datastore_from_other_platform